# toLocaleTimeString() behaviour without arguments in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript

I read in the MDN documentation that:

> toLocaleTimeString() without arguments depends on the
> implementation,the default locale, and the default time zone

What does this mean exactly?

And I tried the following code in both Chrome(Version 87.0.4280.88) and Safari browser(Version 14.0).

```
new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

in Chrome it gives output as

```
16:57:37
```

whereas in Safari it gives output as

```
4:57:37 PM
```

With regards to the above example can someone explain how the implementation is changing from one browser to another, and why is it so?

Edit:
All this was done using MAC, I tried changing preferred language under Setting -> "Language and Region" to English(US) it was English(India) before, as soon as I did that change and restarted chrome the result became.

```
4:57:37 PM
```

But for Safari without doing this change it was able to show in 12 hour format, what was the reason for that?

Comment: Each browser runs a different JavaScript engine. That's how the implementation changes.

Comment: So is Safari's JS engine smart enough to give the 12 hour format without requiring to change the settings -> Language & Region, whereas Chrome's JS engine implements this based on the setting -> Language & Region?

Comment: Is there a place where we can see the code for these different implementations @VLAZ ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "smart" - it's probably just picking the configuration from elsewhere. Or it might be defaulting it differently.

Comment: You should be able to find the source code for all the major engines. V8, SpiderMonkey, and WebKit are all open source.

Comment: @jarmod "*The source to Chromium is available at GitHub; Safari is not.*" ??? https://github.com/WebKit/webkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification for `toLocaleTimeString`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) states:

> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are **implementation-defined**, but are intended to represent the “time” portion of the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form that corresponds to the conventions of the host environment's current locale.

with the [definition of *implementation-defined*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#implementation-defined) being:

> An implementation-defined facility is one that defers its definition
> to an external source without further qualification. This
> specification does not make any recommendations for particular
> behaviours, and conforming implementations are free to choose any
> behaviour within the constraints put forth by this specification.

Therefore browsers are free to implement this feature as they see fit.